# getting error "Illegal conversion from List<AggregateResult> to List<Opportunity>"

Tags: apex, aggregateresult

Here is my code

```
public with sharing class estimatevsPipeline {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Opportunity> getestimatevsPipeline() {
        return [
            SELECT SUM(amount_ge_og__c) sumAmount
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE
                ((IsClosed != TRUE
                AND ForecastCategoryName IN ('Commit', 'Commit at Risk'))
                OR StageName = 'Closed Won')
                AND RecordType.DeveloperName != 'Targets'
                AND Type IN ('Internal to GE Parent', 'Internal to BHGE', 'External')
                AND forecast_pipeline_exception_ge_og__c != TRUE
                AND CloseDate = THIS_QUARTER
                AND Id IN (
                    SELECT OpportunityId
                    FROM OpportunityTeamMember
                    WHERE
                        (UserId IN ('0051H000009S5D2QAK', '00512000007jB49AAE', '0051H00000Aw9VbQAJ')
                        OR UserId = '0051H00000AwEezQAF')
                        AND TeamMemberRole != 'Following'
                )
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @rahulgawale, the error is different from what you suggested.

Comment: Nope, it's the same, the difference is that you are using a different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `SUM` function, this can only be used with Aggregated Queries. If so you should probably `GROUP BY` result by some field and change return type of the method to `List<AggregateResult>`.

If you want just a normal query then remove `SUM` from SELECT.

Here is also [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) on how to use Aggregation in SOQL.

Hopefully, this helps

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar Pandey if I answered your question. please consider marking it as an answer